# Customize wordpress comment form - reply link

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm building a theme for Wordpress on my own and I'm having som problems with my comment form. I want to change the text of the reply"button" (actually it's not a button, it's an a-class with onclick function). Now the default is "reply", but I want to change it to something else. How do a do that?

My php-file looks like this:

```html
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying Comments.
 *
 * The area of the page that contains comments and the comment form.
 *
 */
/*
 * If the current post is protected by a password and the visitor has not yet
 * entered the password we will return early without loading the comments.
 */
if (!empty($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) && 'comments.php' == basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']))
    die('Please do not load this page directly. Thanks!');
if (post_password_required()) {
    ?>
    <p class="nocomments">Det här inlägget är lösenordsskyddat. Knappa in lösenordet för att se inlägget.</p>
    <?php
    return;
}
?>

 <div id="commentsbox" class="post">
     <?php if (have_comments()) : ?>
         <h3 id="comments">
             <?php comments_number('Inga kommentarer',
                 'En kommentar',
                    '% kommentarer'); ?>
              än så länge.</h3>
            <ol class="commentlist">
          <?php wp_list_comments(array(
              'avatar_size' => 70)); ?>
            </ol>
             <div class="comment-nav">
                  <div class="alignleft">
                     <?php previous_comments_link() ?>
                 </div>
                  <div class="alignright">
                <?php next_comments_link() ?>
                  </div>
             </div>
           <?php else : ?>
            <?php if (comments_open()) : ?>
                <?php else :  ?>
                    <p class="nocomments">Kommentarer är avstängda</p>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?> 
                  <?php if (comments_open()) : ?>
               <div class="commentform_wrapper">
                   <div class="post-info">
                   </div>
                     <div id="comment-form">    
                  <?php $comment_args = array( 'title_reply'=>'Vänligen lämna dina synpunkter och kommentarer:',
                   'title_reply_to'    => __( 'Svara %s' ),
                   'cancel_reply_link' => __( 'Stäng svar' ),
                   'label_submit'=>'Skicka',
                   'reply_text' => 'Svara',
              'fields' => apply_filters( 'comment_form_default_fields', array(
               'author' => '<p class="comment-form-author">' . '<label for="author">' . __( 'Namn' ) . '</label> ' . ( $req ? '<span>*</span>' : '' ) .
               '<input id="author" name="author" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author'] ) . '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' /></p>',   
               'email'  => '<p class="comment-form-email">' .
               '<label for="email">' . __( 'Mejl' ) . '</label> ' .
               ( $req ? '<span>*</span>' : '' ) .
               '<input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="' . esc_attr(  $commenter['comment_author_email'] ) . '" size="30"' . $aria_req . ' />'.'</p>',
               'url'    => '' ) ),
               'comment_field' => '<p>' .
               '<label for="comment">' . __( 'Kommentarer' ) . '</label>' .
               '<textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" aria-required="true"></textarea>' .
               '</p>',
               'comment_notes_after' => '',
            );
            comment_form($comment_args); ?>
                    </div>
        </div>
           <?php endif; ?>
 </div>
```

The code that I want to reach looks like this, when inspecting with firebug:

```html
<a class="comment-reply-link" onclick="return addComment.moveForm("div-comment-3", "3", "respond", "40")" href="/?p=40&replytocom=3#respond">Reply</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add into functions.php :

```
   function custom_comment_reply($content) {
        $content = str_replace('Reply', 'Reply to this comment', $content);
        return $content;
   }
   add_filter('comment_reply_link', 'custom_comment_reply');
```

Change " Reply" - "Reply to this comment" .